# Information on usage of tags

Tags: discussion, tags, data-analysis

I've recently started using Stack Overflow. I think it is an excellent data-source of popularity of various languages/frameworks/APIs etc.

Is it possible to make public the data on daily number of questions per tag, for the past few years?

I am a student, and mining this data would make for a very good project :-)

And, I'm generally interested in the results.

Comment: Congratulations, it exists!

Comment: there is this [tag trends by week](http://hewgill.com/~greg/stackoverflow/stack_overflow/tags/) utility from Greg Hewgill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/

Most recent full Creative Commons data dump (as of this writing)

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/creative-commons-data-dump-jun-10/

Web tool hosted in the cloud for querying the data

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/introducing-stack-exchange-data-explorer/

Comment: Answer by Jeff Atwood, Awesome! Has this been done already? Any thought?