# Ok to edit out feature-request for features that exist?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta

Here on Meta we sometimes have `feature-request` for features that already exist.  In these cases is it acceptable to edit out the `feature-request` tag?

My example is [Information on usage of Tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54699/information-on-usage-of-tags), and in this case he specifically said he wasn't sure if it should be a feature request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The feature is still a "feature-request" even though it already exists. It can't really be considered "discussion" because they are specifically asking for something.

Just mark as duplicate (if possible) of the other feature request, or flag for moderator attention and have them tag it as "Status-Completed" because the feature exists. That way, any other confused users who appear on Meta will be able to search and find the feature request that already exists.

**EDIT** If you're talking about stream-lining so that it does not influence the moderators or site owners who are monitoring those tags, it is still worthwhile to know that there are features that are already implemented that are too obscure to be found by some users.

Comment: @ccomet [status-bydesign] tends to be used for *rejecting* feature requests.

Comment: Even in the case of the guy who said he wasn't sure?

Comment: Even in the case. The fact is, it *is* a feature, which started (as most do) as a feature request. So the "feature request" part is still valid, because someone felt the feature was good enough to implement.

Comment: True about rejection. I'll retract that comment.